# Removing app cache

Tags: cache, cairo-dock

I recently installed cairo-dock, and it was working great, but now it is all buggy, so I tried to reinstall. I did

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock
sudo apt-get clean
sudo reboot now
```

Then when I came back on, it was gone, so I thought it would be fine to reinstall.. I was wrong... I did

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

And when it reinstalled, the app cache was still there. Is there any way that I can remove the entire cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you unninstall a program, the settings are kept under your $HOME/ in case you want to use them again. In the case of cairo-dock, there are stored under:

```
/home/<yourusername>/.config/cairo-dock
```

So if you want to reset to defaults, all you need to do is open a terminal and run:

```
rm -rvf ~/.config/cairo-dock
```

This will delete all the settings (without asking you for confirmation!) and when you re-run cairo-dock it will load with the default ones.